# How to receive the file sent from curl in an express file?

Tags: node.js, express, curl

I want to accept the file sent in the request object from the curl CLI and modify it in my express.js server.

For example:
User attempts as such:

```
curl -T somefile.txt https://example.com/uploadfile
```

Accept it in:

```
app.put("/uploadfile", function (req, res) {
  // access the file here
});
```

Comment: Look at `multer` and how to use it to get files in Express

Answer (score 1):

`curl -T somefile.txt https://example.com/uploadfile` produces the following request:

```
PUT /uploadfile/somefile.txt HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Accept: */*
Content-Length: ...
Expect: 100-continue

<contents of the .txt file>
```

Therefore you need a middleware like

```js
app.put("/uploadfile/:filename", function(req, res) {
  /* Access the the file as the readable stream req, for example: */
  req.pipe(process.stdout);
  res.end();
});
```

Node.js handles the `Expect` header automatically, see [here](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/http.html#event-checkcontinue).